# Build fail with an error about fs-extra module, using circle cI and create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, circleci

I have been trying to use circle ci with create react app, but I confronted this error.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
CI=true npm run build
```

```
> react-scripts build

/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir.js:85
      } catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:613:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! robofriends@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the robofriends@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/circleci/.npm/_logs/2021-09-24T23_47_26_734Z-debug.log


Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

These are my simple setup.

```yaml
# .circleci/config.yml

version: 2.1
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:9.8
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: echo "npm installing"
      - run: npm install
      - run: CI=true npm run build
```

```json
// package.json

"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-redux": "^7.2.4",
"react-scripts": "^4.0.3"
```

Does anyone have any clue why this error comes up?
Would this be about node version or something?...

Comment: I have changed the node image to the latest and it worked!! 
` - image: circleci/node:latest`

Comment: You can answer your own question instead of commenting it :)

Comment: Oh, I'm new. Thanks @Shahriar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the node image to the latest and it worked!!

`- image: circleci/node:latest`